OpenSearch Trace Analytics : Latency while sending traces through DataPrepper
I am sending OTLP traces to an OTEL collector, which then sends it to a DataPrepper instance and then finally to an OpenSearch backend.
Application Traces → OTEL Collector → DataPrepper → OpenSearch
The issue Im facing is that for traces with multiple spans, there is a delay from trace generation to being able to view them on OpenSearch Dashboards. The traces can be viewed on OpenSearch Dashboards, only after 5-10 minutes after the original trace is generated and sent by the application.
Setup:

OpenSearch and Dashboards v 2.12.0
DataPrepper v 2.7 & 2.8
OTEL Collector v 0.102.1
OS : Oracle Linux 8

Configuration:
OTEL Collector
extensions:
  health_check:
receivers:
  otlp:
    protocols:
      grpc:
        endpoint: 0.0.0.0:4317
      http:
        endpoint: 0.0.0.0:4318
  prometheus:
    config:
      scrape_configs:
      - job_name: 'otel-collector'
        scrape_interval: 10s
        static_configs:
        - targets: ['0.0.0.0:8888']
processors:
  batch:
    send_batch_size: 500
    timeout: 1s
exporters:
  debug:
    verbosity: detailed
    sampling_initial: 5
    sampling_thereafter: 200
  otlp/data-prepper:
    endpoint: '<dataprepper-ip>:21890'
    tls:
      insecure: true
service:
  pipelines:
    traces:
      receivers: [otlp]
      processors: [batch]
      exporters: [debug,otlp/data-prepper]

DataPrepper Configuration
entry-pipeline:
  workers: 4    
  delay: "5"
  source:
    otel_trace_source:
      ssl: false
  buffer:
    bounded_blocking:
      buffer_size: 25600
      batch_size: 500
  sink:
    - pipeline:
        name: "raw-trace-pipeline"
    - pipeline:
        name: "service-map-pipeline"
raw-trace-pipeline:
  workers: 8      
  source:
    pipeline:
      name: "entry-pipeline"
  buffer:
    bounded_blocking:
      buffer_size: 25600
      batch_size: 500
  processor:
    - otel_trace_raw:
  sink:
    - opensearch:
        hosts: ["https://localhost:9200"]
        insecure: true
        username: admin
        password: admin
        index_type: trace-analytics-raw     
service-map-pipeline:
  workers: 8
  delay: "5"
  source:
    pipeline:
      name: "entry-pipeline"
  buffer:
    bounded_blocking:
      buffer_size: 25600
      batch_size: 500
  processor:
    - service_map_stateful:
  sink:
    - opensearch:
        hosts: ["https://localhost:9200"]
        insecure: true
        username: admin
        password: admin
        index_type: trace-analytics-service-map

I have reviewed the OTEL collector logs and found that the traces are being forwarded almost instantly to DataPrepper once recieved. It looks like DataPrepper might be taking a long time to process the traces with multple spans and send them to OpenSearch.
At the moment, I am testing with individual traces (around 150KB) so I do not believe that it should be taking this long even with default DataPrepper configuration.
I have tried increasing the heap size, increasing the number of workers and also buffer sizes to no avail…
I am also not seeing any warning/error messages on DataPrepper logs (debug enabled)
Any help is appreciated, thanks.
